# editAction function in twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I am new to symfon2 struked in some part in the controller page in edit function. I need to render to my create page with the all the information when i click on edit in the view.html.twig

My Controller.php,

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    $profile = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('TcprofileBundle:TcProfiles')
                    ->find($id);

    $profile_form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $profile);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $profile_form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tcprofile_create', array('id' => $id)));
     }
}
```

My view.twig template

```
  <a href="#!{{ path('tcprofile_edit',{ 'id': profile.getId}) }}"> Edit Profile </a>
```

My routing,

```
 tcprofile_edit:
     pattern: /edit/{id}
     defaults: { _controller: "TcprofileBundle:Default:edit"}  `
```

please help me better solutions , Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to use AJAX to load the content of the edit page? Does it work without using AJAX?

Comment: Seems like some bits are missing, like a template for your form. Or perhaps an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form with Entity data. just pass the entity to the createForm function. When the form is rendered it will contain the entity data ;)

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    $profile = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('TcprofileBundle:TcProfiles')
                    ->find($id);

    $profile_form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $profile);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $profile_form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

       return $this->render('bundle:edit:editForm.html.twig' , $profile_form);
     }
}
```

you'll have the form loaded with the default data.